# What does "Modified by Community" mean?

Tags: discussion

I see this tag from time to time and was wondering just what it means. I'm guessing that it signifies some action by a moderator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a form of moderated activity, but not by one of us. If we take an action, it's recorded as being taken by us rather than through an anonymous account.

You can see some about that "user" here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community